# VB.NET Chat Server Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, tcp, chat

I recently got into this [article](http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_chat_server.htm). It makes a chat server and people can connect to it like an AIM. The problem how would I disconnect from the server from the client. Because if I close the client application when its connected to the server it will crash the server as well. Please let me know if anyone has any solutions...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wherever in your code the crash is occurring, you need to set a try/catch block to catch a Connection Closed exception.

Comment: What is the Connection Code exception called?

Comment: I just call it Try/ Catch ex as Exception/End try kind of thing